# Как изменить скорость загрузки сайта?

Tags: браузер, тестирование, splash-screen

Пишу `splash-screen` для сайта. Странички маленькие - загружаются быстро, поэтому страница-загрузчик проскакивает вообще незаметно, даже моргнуть не успевает.

Надо бы как-то ограничить скорость, чтобы всё это загружалось помедленнее, чтобы можно было отследить по шагам процесс загрузки страницы.

На работе стоит `Windows 7`, дома - `Debian 9`. Вопрос актуален для обеих операционных систем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> чтобы всё это загружалось помедленнее

В `Chrome DevTools` есть специальный инструмент для тестирования веб-приложений в условиях медленной сети или даже оффлайн. Называется он `Network Throttling`.

Нажимаете <kbd>F12</kbd>, вкладка `Network/Сеть`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]