# Как можно симулировать тормозящий браузер?

Tags: веб-программирование, тестирование

В веб разработке встречаются такой момент, когда у клиента с очень медленным интернетом и старой медленной системой во время открытия в веб страницы видны ее дефекты, которые на быстрых машинах не видны так как их человек не успевает заметить. Как можно симулировать вот такую медленную загрузку, что бы увидеть подобные дефекты при веб разработке?

да это дубликат вопроса:
[Изменить скорость загрузки сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745219/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)
но там нет решения моей проблемы:

Comment: Купить за копейки такой комп))) Ну или на виртуалке сделать virtualbox например. урезать все ресурсы

Comment: запустите в торренте на скачивание фильмографию Джеки Чана)

Comment: Купить старую медленную машину и поставить ограничение трафика в роутере?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ) и остановить работу всей организации?

Comment: Точно видел такую штуку в Хроме, где-то рядом с эмуляцией мобильных устройств. Не надо никаких виртуалок и тем более нового старого (кхм?) железа.

Comment: @perfect Нет, ограничение трафика выставить только на том выходе роутера, на котором висит старая медленная машина. :-)

Comment: devtools -> Network -> В конце второй строки будет "Online".

Comment: @D-side да. подойдет и такое. я на freebsd видил надстройку над tcp/ip протоколом (ipdummy кажется) там можно было чередовать полезные и пустые пакеты для ограничения скорости. я как то так это представлял. за посказку спасибо посмотрю

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно использовать какую-нибудь утилиту для искусственного ограничения скорости, например https://www.netlimiter.com/

Кроме того можно использовать встроенный аудит в Chrome:

> [image]

но он в основном статистику и анализ показывает, а не показывает это в реальном времени, хотя еще в network можно ограничить скорость:

> [image]

Еще для ограничения скорости можно использовать vpn для хрома, они чаще всего сильно рубят скорость

Answer (score 1):

У себя на работе при тестировании создаём ограничение 2 Гб на процесс в [cgroups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups#Manual_usage) для Firefox и Google Chrome.

Ещё ограничиваем частоту CPU с помощью `cpupower set-frequency -u 1GHz -g powersave`.

При разработке - ограничиваем производительность средствами разработчика в Chrome (кажется с 62-й версии можно ограничивать CPU).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: Работаем под Linux.

Comment: cpupower - на virtualbox работать будет?

Comment: попробовал на последней убунте падает эта программа

Comment: Думаю, что virtualbox - работать не будет (скорее будут использоватся настройки хоста). Нужно проверять.
Я бы посмотрел в сторону лимита на cpu в cgroups.